# Relative Entropy and the Wasserstein distance

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, concentration-of-measure, optimal-transport

Can anyone give an informative example of two distributions which have a low Wasserstein distance but high relative entropy (or the other way around)? I find the Wasserstein, defined (for some $p$) as

$$ W_p(\mu,\nu)=\left(\inf_{\pi\in\Pi(\mu,\nu)}\int d^p(x,y)\pi(dx,dy)\right)^{1/p},$$

an intuitive, reasonable way to calculate the distance (or displacement) between two probability measures.

However I'm struggling to see what **relative entropy** really tells us. I have seen from **Sanov's theorem** that it can be used to control the exponential rate of decay of the probability of a rare event, however I still haven't got an intuitive feel for how it works and would really appreciate a concrete example so I can compare it against the Wasserstein. I have heard that relative entropy controls the fluctuation of one distribution w.r.t another, however, I haven't yet quite understood what this means.

Comment: does (or how would) this question pertain to the usage of the entropy-regularized optimal transport, which contains both of the measures mentioned in the question title?

Answer (score 4):

For an example, look at the point masses $\delta_0$ and $\delta_h$ supported at $0$ and $h$, respectively.  The Wasserstein distance between these is $O(h)$, which is small if $h$ is small. But for $h\ne0$ the relative entropy is infinitely large, as the two measures are mutually singular.

For an example the other way around, let $f(x)$ be the density of a $U[0,N]$ rv, and let $$g(x)=(1-\epsilon)f(x)$$ for $x\in[0,N/2]$ and $$g(x)=(1+\epsilon)f(x)$$ otherwise.

The Wasserstein distance is something like $O(N\epsilon)$ (because we have to transfer like $\epsilon$ of the mass over distance $N/2$, but the relative entropy is something like $O(\epsilon)$ because $\log f(x)/g(x) = O(\epsilon)$.  By proper choice of $\epsilon$, we can make the Wasserstein distance big but the relative entropy small.

The intuitive picture I have in mind, is that when one looks at the superimposed graphs of the densities of the two measures (pretending that they *have* densities) is that the relative entropy measures how much they differ in a vertical sense only, but the Wasserstein metric allows for sideways nudgings of the two graphs.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks!, but surely making epsilon small in your 2nd example makes both the relative entropy and the wasserstien smaller? Still really appreciate any other examples from people:)

Comment: Can anyone help with this related question: Why can't the Wasserstein distance equal $0$ if $\mu = \nu$? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3897273