# If $\alpha = \beta$, why can't the entropy-regularized Wasserstein distance equal $0$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, entropy, regularization, optimal-transport

In optimal transportation theory, the optimal re-allocation of probability distribution $\alpha$'s mass to another distribution $\beta$ is solved by minimizing the **Wasserstein distance** with respect to the transport plan.

$$W (\alpha, \beta) = \min_{\pi\in \Pi(\alpha\beta)} \int c(x,y) \mathrm{d}\pi(x,y) $$

Alternatively, the relative entropy-regularized Wasserstein distance, also called **Sinkhorn distance**, can be used:

$$W_\epsilon (\alpha, \beta) = \min_{\pi\in \Pi(\alpha\beta)} \int c(x,y) \mathrm{d}\pi(x,y) + \epsilon H(\pi \| \alpha \otimes \beta)$$
where $\epsilon$ is the regularization parameter, and relative entropy is$$H(\pi \| \alpha \otimes \beta) = \int \ln \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\pi (x,y)}{\mathrm{d}\alpha(x)  \mathrm{d}\beta(y)  } \right) \mathrm{d}\pi (x,y) $$
Aude Genevay said that if you try the extreme case where both the source and target distributions are identical, $\alpha = \beta$, then *we would expect* the entropy-regularized Wasserstein distance (Sinkhorn distance) to equal $0$ since there is nothing to move, *however it is incapable of doing so*. Because of this she proposes the **Sinkhorn divergence** instead, a normalization which does equal $0$ if $\alpha = \beta$:

$$\bar{W}_\epsilon (\alpha, \beta) = W_\epsilon (\alpha, \beta) - \frac{1}{2} [W_\epsilon (\alpha, \alpha) + W_\epsilon (\beta, \beta) ]$$
In other words, $\bar{W}_\epsilon (\alpha, \alpha) = 0$.

### Questions

1. Why (or for what levels of regularization) can't the Sinkhorn
   distance, shown earlier, achieve $0$?
2. Does standard optimal transport, which uses the unregularized
   Wasserstein distance, also suffer from this incapability (even
   though I know that the Wasserstein distance by itself, without OT,
   will achieve $0$)?
3. and why, mathematically, does the Sinkhorn divergence?

Comment: It's a rewarding exercise if you make clear for yourself why $W(\alpha,\alpha)=0$ is actually true.

Comment: because $\alpha=\alpha$? but why $W_{\epsilon}(\alpha,\alpha)\neq 0$ even when $\epsilon=0$?

Comment: No it doesn't work so easily. Plug in $\alpha$ for both measures in your minimisation problem above. Why does it give the value zero? It's not hard to prove that, yet it's non-trivial (and also this doesn't just follow from the fact that $W$ is a metric, because this is part of actually proving that $W$ is a metric, which is by no means obviuos!). And understanding that will also illuminate why $W_{\epsilon}$ is deviating.

Comment: hope you can demonstrate whatever it is you're trying to say in an answer

Comment: I'll just repeat my genuinely well-intentioned advice: first realise why $W(\alpha,\alpha)=0$ holds.

Answer (score 4):

1. To show why this is the case I think the way to go about things is to consider the first term in

$$W_\epsilon (\alpha, \beta) = \min_{\pi\in \Pi(\alpha,\beta)} \int c(x,y) \mathrm{d}\pi(x,y) + \epsilon H(\pi \| \alpha \otimes \beta)$$

and note it is only zero when $\pi(A,B)=\pi(A\cap B,A\cap B)$ (i.e when $\pi$ puts all the mass onto the diagonal $x=y$), otherwise it is positive. Then you are just left to check what happens  to $\epsilon H(\pi \| \alpha \otimes \beta)$ when $\pi$ is of such a form.

2. When you say "even though I know that the Wasserstein distance by itself, without OT, will achieve 0 " this doesn't really make sense the Wasserstein distance is an OT problem itself. To see why $W_2(\alpha,\alpha)=0$ take as a $\gamma=f_\#\alpha$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \text{diag}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is defined as $f(x)=(x,x)$, and define as a candidate $\pi\in\Pi(\alpha,\beta)$ (not necessarily optimal) $\pi(A)=\gamma(A \cap \text{diag}(\mathbb{R}^d))$. Note $\text{diag}(\mathbb{R}^d)=\{(x,x)\in\mathbb{R}^{2d}~:~x\in\mathbb{R}^d\}$
3. Are you asking how $\tilde{W}_\epsilon(\alpha,\alpha)=W_\epsilon(\alpha,\alpha)-\frac{1}{2}(W_\epsilon(\alpha,\alpha)+W_\epsilon(\alpha,\alpha))=0$?

---

Edit : for 1) and $c(x,y)=\|x-y\|^2$ proceed like this :

- Note that since $H(\pi|\gamma)=\int h(\frac{d\pi}{d\gamma})d\gamma$ for $h(x)=x\log x$ which is strictly convex. Hence using Jensen $H(\pi|\gamma)\geq 0$ with equality IFF $\frac{d\pi}{d\gamma}$ is constant, i.e. $\gamma=\pi$.
- So we are forced to consider (where we set $M_i$ equal to the i-th moment of $\alpha$)
  $$ \frac{1}{2}\int \|x-y\|^2 d\alpha(x)d\alpha (y) = M_2-\int x\cdot y d\alpha(x)d\alpha(y) \geq M_2 -M_1^2 >0,$$

where in the last line we used Jensens inequality for the strictly convex function $x\mapsto x^2$.

Comment: Yes I am asking why the Wasserstein distance $$W (\alpha, \beta) = \min_{\pi\in \Pi(\alpha\beta)} \int c(x,y) \mathrm{d}\pi(x,y)$$ and the Sinkhorn divergence $$\tilde{W}_\epsilon(\alpha,\alpha)=W_\epsilon(\alpha,\alpha)-\frac{1}{2}(W_\epsilon(\alpha,\alpha)+W_\epsilon(\alpha,\alpha))$$  can both collapse to $0$ if $\alpha=\beta$, but  the Sinkhorn distance can't: $$W_\epsilon (\alpha, \beta) = \min_{\pi\in \Pi(\alpha\beta)} \int c(x,y) \mathrm{d}\pi(x,y) + \epsilon H(\pi \| \alpha \otimes \beta)$$

Comment: For $W$ pick the transport plan $\pi$ that puts all mass onto the diagonal $x=y$. For $\tilde{W}_\epsilon$ your asking why $W_\epsilon(\alpha,\alpha)-W_\epsilon(\alpha,\alpha)=0$... read the expression... For Sinkhorn distance go watch\read the material by Aude (this was not part of your original question).

Comment: why the sinkhorn distance can't achieve 0 was the first question on the list

Comment: Oh yeah sorry! As I said in my answer try that.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, because if you consider a general positive Borel cost function $c$ the object you're calling Wasserstein distance is instead an OT problem. It is called Wasserstein distance only when the cost is a metric. This in my opinion could lead to some confusion.

Indeed, the property $W(\alpha, \alpha) = 0$ is true for the Wasserstein distance because we can use the fact that $\|x-y\|=0$ means that the OT maps the mass on $\{x=y\}$ which is saying that the marginals measures are equal (easily prove that if you marginalize the coupling you have the same quantity). I don't see how this could hold for a general cost $c$.

Moreover, if you consider the same problem with the entropic regularizer the same arguments hold while if you consider the cost to be some norm you can reason the same way.
Suppose there exists an optimal coupling $\gamma^*$ such that the entropic regularized Wasserstein is zero, i.e.
$$ \int \|x-y\| + \epsilon\log\left(\frac{d\gamma^*}{d\alpha d\beta}\right)d\gamma^*=0.$$
Since both terms in the integral are nonnegative then the singular terms are zero $\gamma^*$- a.s. Therefore $\|x-y\|=0$ $\gamma^*$-a.s. and we are in the same scenario as the Wasserstein distance.